# Rails render partial does not use @instance_variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, renderpartial

I'm trying to render a partial, but it's not using my `@user_name` variable. When you render a partial in a controller, do you need to do something special to pass in variables?

Looking at the Rails guides, I didn't see anything that said @instance_variables wouldn't be available in a partial.

Here is my user#new controller:

```
  def new
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @user = User.new
    end

    # Used to show "log in" instead of "sign up" on render. Set in URL request.
    if params[:show_log_in] == true
      @show_log_in = true; //???? doesn't seem to get passed into partial.
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      # JS is used for modal windows when this is accessed asynchronously.
      # e.g. a button is clicked that requires user to be signed in.
      format.js { render "shared/_signup_modal.html.erb" } //???? @show_log_in doesnt seem to get passed in?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables defined in controller would be available in views, including partial. There is no doubt. But the problem is not here.

The problem is about `params`. `params` values are all in String. So, the evaluation `if params[:show_log_in] == true` is wrong and always returns false, and the instance defined there will never be sent.

You need to compare it as a string.

```
if params[:show_log_in] == "true"
```

Moreover, it is not good you render a HTML partial in a JS response. I'm not sure if this will work but the legit way is to render `js.erb` file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable.  In your respond_to block, you'll want `format.js {@show_log_in}`.  I typically use `respond_to` and `respond_with` though.  It's prettier.

Then, you'll have to make an adjustment in your view.

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#selector').html("<%= j render partial: 'shared/_signup_modal' %>");
```

The partial you're rendering there will have access to the `@variables` you pass it.